# Android:dialog box issue

Tags: android

I use the Progress Dialog ,first time when I load the web view and create the object in OnCreate

```
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressBar.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {

            if (progressBar.isShowing())
                progressBar.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    progressBar.show();
```

and dismiss it onPageFinished

```
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("TEST", "Finished loading URL: " + url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
```

then I load another url from menu then I write the code in onPageStarted

```
                   @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                 if(progressBar.isShowing()){}

                 else
                 //progressBar.
                 progressBar.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
```

on second time the circle in Dialog is not running, all everything works fine.
  you can view same problem in ApiDemos alos.
  please install Apidemos application in device then go to view->progress bar->dialog->click on "show Intermediat"
  then dismiss using back button.Now add click on same button, the circle animation will working

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting the call to the base class (super.onPageStarted) before your call to show the progress bar?

Comment: yes i have call to super call using super.onPageStarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue is related to activity because when we dismiss the dialog activity store it value so second time call it load the same state of dialog so need to implement the onPrepareDialog for resetting the new value and use the removeDialog(int) just before the showing. please check it out [ProgressBar does not reset to "0" when opening the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851694/progressbar-not-reset-to-0-when-opening-the-second-time?tab=active#tab-top)

code here

```
   @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_WEBVIEW:
            progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressBar.setCancelable(true);
            //mProgressDialog.show();
            return;
        default:
            return ;
        }
        //super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    }
```

for onCreateDialog

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_WEBVIEW:
                progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressBar.show();
                return progressBar;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

lastly to show,dismiss and remove like this

```
                            removeDialog(DIALOG);
                showDialog(DIALOG); 
                            dismissDialog(DIALOG);
```