# Progress Dialog displaying problem second time in webview with backbutton?

Tags: android, webview

i am using following code to display progressDialog in webview.
normally every thing works fine but while progress dialog loading i press backbutton and come to same activity with webview again it does not show progress dialog immediately but after a while and repeating this two three times application crashes.

while showing _dialog.show() onPageStarted. i have seen post

[ProgressDialog created from onCreateDialog stops animating on second run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821306/progressdialog-created-from-oncreatedialog-stops-animating-on-second-run)

[Android:dialog box issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992853/androiddialog-box-issue)

but no use.

any one guide me what is the solution to this problem?

```
private static final int DIALOG_WEBVIEW = 0;
    private WebView _webView;
    private ProgressDialog _dialog;

oncreate()
{
_webView.canGoBack();

        _webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }



            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {




                showDialog(DIALOG_WEBVIEW); // crashes here

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


                if(_dialog.isShowing())
                {

                    removeDialog(DIALOG_WEBVIEW);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                if (Constants.LOG)Log.d("recieved error-------------------------", "");
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

                if(_dialog.isShowing())
                {

                    removeDialog(DIALOG_WEBVIEW);
                }
            }


        });


}


@Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_WEBVIEW:
          _dialog.setMessage(Constants.TEXT_PLEASE_WAIT);
            _dialog.setCancelable(true);

            return;
        default:
            return ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case DIALOG_WEBVIEW:
            {
                _dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                 _dialog.show();
                 return _dialog;
            }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

log cat

```
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@406b7138 is not valid; is your activity running?
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.mobile.modules.volunteer.VolunteerScreenNew.onCreateDialog(VolunteerScreenNew.java:343)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2482)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:882)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2557)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.mobile.modules.volunteer.VolunteerScreenNew$1.onPageStarted(VolunteerScreenNew.java:181)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:264)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 11:43:16.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: One thing that sticks up is that you don't need to keep a reference to the loading dialog. In the `onPrepareDialog` use the `Dialog` parameter that is provided to you, that will be whatever you returned in `onCreateDialog`.  Though I'm not sure if that causes the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we can override the back button action by using the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK&& event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
{
onBackPressed();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

create a method onBackPressed() and dismiss the dialog in that and start anather activity.

Comment: no it does not make any sense as onBackPressed is for 2.* or later where as onkeydown was alternative to this in previous versions and still usable.

Comment: call the method finish() in onBackPressed() it will close the entire activity

Comment: thanks for helping me i have done that but still problem exists it is dialog related problem.